# cant see swagger json in localhost using play-swagger repository

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger, swagger-ui, content-security-policy

I have done everything the github documentation mentioned:

added plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.iheart" %% "sbt-play-swagger" % "0.7.3")
```

added to my root:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, SwaggerPlugin) //enable plugin
```

added a base swagger.yml

added the library:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" % "swagger-ui" % "2.2.0"
```

added those to my routes:

```
### NoDocs ###
GET   /docs/swagger-ui/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path:String="/public/lib/swagger-ui", file:String)

### NoDocs ###
GET   /assets/*file                 controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

and added some swagger annotation to my routes.

now when I run the app and go to http://localhost:9000/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/assets/swagger.json im supposed to see something, and all I see is a green screen...

[image]

so weird, is there something missing in the doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your version of play-swagger it looks like you're using it with Play 2.6. This version of Play introduces [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) headers by default.  There is a known [issue](https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger/issues/174) with Play 2.6's CSP headers and play-swagger.

If you look in your browser console you should see some CSP errors logged. If this is the case you may need to [disable the headers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders#Configuring-the-security-headers) by adding the following to your `application.conf` file.

```
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = null
```

We are working on an [improvement](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/8242) to Play's Content Security Policy header implementation so that third-party libraries like play-swagger should work more seamlessly in the future.